# How to build a summary data frame

Tags: r, summary

I have a data set looks like this:

[image]

and I would like to get a summary data set that will looks like this:
[image]

what should i do? Thanks. The sample.data can be build through following codes:

```
ID<- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18")
Group<-c("A","B","C","D","D","D","A","B","D","C","B","D","A","A","C","B","B","B")
Color<-c("Green","Yellow","Red","Red","Red","Yellow","Green","Green","Yellow","Red","Red","Yellow","Yellow","Yellow","Green","Red","Red","Green")
Realy_Love<-c("Y","N","Y","Y","N","N","Y","Y","Y","N","N","Y","N","Y","N","Y","N","Y")
Sample.data <- data.frame(ID, Group, Color, Realy_Love)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` and group by the following items:

```
Sample.data %>%
  group_by(Group, Color, Realy_Love) %>%
  summarise(Obs = n())

# Group Color  Realy_Love   Obs
# <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <int>
# 1 A     Green  Y              2
# 2 A     Yellow N              1
# 3 A     Yellow Y              1
# 4 B     Green  Y              2
# 5 B     Red    N              2
# 6 B     Red    Y              1
# 7 B     Yellow N              1
# 8 C     Green  N              1
# 9 C     Red    N              1
# 10 C     Red    Y              1
# 11 D     Red    N              1
# 12 D     Red    Y              1
# 13 D     Yellow N              1
# 14 D     Yellow Y              2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dplyr from the Tidyverse to get a summary. You can then use `arrange()` to sort by Color or another variable.

```
  group_by(Group, Color, Realy_Love) %>% 
  summarise(Obs = n()) %>% 
  arrange(Color)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, you even don't need to group the columns, just use one step solution with the [`count()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/count.html) function:

```
Sample.data %>%
    count(Group, Color, Realy_Love, sort = TRUE)
```

The optional `sort = TRUE` argument says to sort with descending order from the most frequent:

```
   Group  Color Realy_Love n
1      A  Green          Y 2
2      B  Green          Y 2
3      B    Red          N 2
4      D Yellow          Y 2
5      A Yellow          N 1
6      A Yellow          Y 1
7      B    Red          Y 1
8      B Yellow          N 1
9      C  Green          N 1
10     C    Red          N 1
11     C    Red          Y 1
12     D    Red          N 1
13     D    Red          Y 1
14     D Yellow          N 1
```